# What is '_autodiscover._tcp' in DNS settings?

Tags: domain-name-system, autodiscovery

On a domain, in the DNS settings is an SRV record named:

```
_autodiscover._tcp
```

and value is:

```
0 10 443 autodiscover.*hostname*.net.
```

What is it and what does it do?

I am migrating websites to a new server and I need to know how this will work with the new server on a different host.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[SRV DNS records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record) allow the use of DNS for publishing services and service discovery. Their main use is to allow services to run easily on non-standard ports and to reduce the configuration burden when setting up clients.

A SRV record has the following form:

```
_Service._Protocol.Name. TTL Class SRV Priority Weight Port Target
```

- **Service**: the symbolic name of the service.
- **Protocol**: the transport protocol of the service; this is usually either TCP or UDP.
- **Name**: the domain name terminated with a <kbd>.</kbd> for which this record is valid - often omitted in DNS shorthand which then
  defaults to the zone name.
- **TTL**: standard DNS time to live field.
- **Class**: standard DNS class field (this is always `IN` for Internet).
- **Priority**: the priority of the target host, lower value means more preferred.
- **Weight**: A relative weight for records with the same priority.
- **Port**: the TCP or UDP port on which the service is to be found.
- **Target**: the canonical hostname of the machine providing the service.

Yours appears an example of an **autodiscovery** service :) pointing to `TCP port 443` on the aptly named host `autodiscover.*hostname*.net.`

One such autodiscovery service seems to be used in automatically configuring [MS Outlook](http://www.msexchange.org/articles-tutorials/exchange-server-2007/mobility-client-access/Uncovering-New-Outlook-2007-Discover-Service.html) but that may not be the only use-case.

Answer (score 5):

It is likely related to your Exchange server.

[Autodiscover for Exchange](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/autodiscover-for-exchange#querying-dns-for-an-srv-record).

Comment: Absolutely, and it allows Outlook to "discover the Exchange autodiscover service", whatever that means. See also: [A new feature is available that enables Outlook 2007 to use DNS Service Location (SRV) records to locate the Exchange Autodiscover service](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/940881). Not all domains may have it, so I suppose this is used to override a default that Outlook tries. Looks like there is an IIS server at the endpoint indicated.

Answer (score 0):

These services enable things like email clients, FTP clients, etc to validate the mail or (S)FTP server name so as to enjoy greater security.

If such checking were not automatically done for email download, it might happen that a malicious email purporting to use **your** business email address as a sender (but actually emanating from a hacker employed by a rival business) could send an email to your bank with a separate *Reply-To* address (controlled by the hacker) and, if the recipient accepts the email as genuine, thus obtain sensitive information about your business.

Have a read [here](https://www.pscs.co.uk/manual/dns-srv-autodiscover.html).